# Saving in the WF4 WorkflowDesigner

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

How do I save the XAML for a WF4 workflow in a rehosted designer, **without** writing it to a file? I want to store the serialised workflow in a database as an XML string.

Given a WorkflowDesigner instance called w, this saves to a file fine:

```
WorkflowDesigner.Flush();
w.Save("filename.xaml");
```

I was hoping this would serialise to a string - but it fails:

```
WorkflowDesigner.Flush();
var modelService = WorkflowDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>();
var workflow = modelService.Root;
var xml = XamlServices.Save(workflow);
```

... while saving a single Sequence activity, it says "Type 'System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItemImpl' not visible. If the type is local, please set the LocalAssembly field in XamlReaderSettings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use Flush() and Text to get the xaml as a string. Use Save() to save to a file or stream, no Flush() needed in that case.

Comment: The Text property seems to have some extra tags in the XML for viewstate, but it works fine.

Comment: The ViewState elements are for the designer and also there is you save to file or stream. You can safely remove all the extra elements and attributes and you workflow will execute just fine. The VS experience, like debugging and stepping through the workflow, will degrade though.

Comment: @Maurice How to remove the ViewState elements before executing the workflow?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I haven't used this; the API seems a bit... odd.  But from the docs, it appears that when you call `Flush()` on the instance of the `WorkflowDesigner`, it saves the current workflow to a public property called `Text`.  You should be able to grab that text and stick it in your database just fine.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowdesigner.text.aspx):

> Before getting this value, call
>   Flush() to convert the current
>   workflow to text. After setting this
>   value, call Load() to load the XAML
>   into the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Using [ActivityXamlServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.xamlintegration.activityxamlservices.createbuilderwriter.aspx) and a StringWriter to flush the content to a string.